# Pixi.js generate SpriteSheet Animation or MovieClip from an animated gif file

Tags: javascript, gif, animated-gif, sprite-sheet, pixi.js

I am making a game that allows the player to link to their own gif images and immediately make them playable in the game, and need to convert animated .gif files into spritesheets.

I have a jsfiddle that will load any image you past into the input, but it only loads the first frame:

http://jsfiddle.net/40k7g0cL/

```
var animatedGif = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('http://i.imgur.com/egzJbiI.gif');
```

But pixi.js asset loader can only seem to load the first frame of an animated .gif file and not the rest.

All the information I can find on this subject says I should convert the animated .gif file into a SpriteSheet ahead of time, however this is not possible because the player is going to be supplying the .gif images as they play, so I can not pre-process them ahead of time.

Is there an easy way to load an animated .gif image, having it automatically converted to a SpriteSheet or MovieClip or even an array of Texture objects?

If there is not a simple solution already in pixi.js, do I need to write my own plugin, perhaps using something like [jsgif](https://github.com/shachaf/jsgif) to process the .gif and separate each frame manually?

Any suggestions on how to go about generating a SpriteSheet from an animated .gif client-side in the browser (in javascript) could be useful.

Comment: I know you wanted in the browser but there is a nice service you can use as well try http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/extract_frames_from_an_animated_gif#play_button_overlay

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there is no way to achieve this directly with pixi.js.

As you suggest, it seems that **jsgif** is the only low-level implementation of *gif* for client-side javascript. Also, exists a fork of this called **[libgif-js](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js)**, a little easier to analyze, and it can offer a clue for build the SpriteSheet.

The process to separate the frames would be:

- **Load the image data.**
  If your app is online, you have to use the File API ([see here](http://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files)) to read local files.
  You'll get an `ArrayBuffer` or `String` with the gif's raw data, that can be passed to `new Stream(data)`.
- **Parse the data:**
  Call `parseGIF(stream, handler)`. The second library can help a lot to understand this process.
  Customize handler and callbacks to get what you need (width, height, frames...).
- **Create your SpriteSheet according to your rules:**
  If you chose save the frames as `ImageData`, use a hidden canvas (it can be the same that in the parse) to draw them in the right positions to form your SpriteSheet.
- **Take the final image and use it:**
  You can use, for example, `canvas.toDataURL(*format*)` (first, resize canvas to SpriteSheet dimensions) to get the image as a base64 url.